# Refresh a SelectOneMenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2

I have two SelectOneMenu. The first contains the list of countries and I would like the second one to contain the list of cities according to the country chosen in the first drop-down list. To do this, I proceed as follows:
First of all, in my list containing the list of countries, I listen to any change in value like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="#{val['inscription.country']}"><h:outputText value="#{val['inscription.country']}"/><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="#{val['inscription.country']}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{val['requiredcountry']}" value="#{manageuser.country}" styleClass="form-control" validator="#{manageuser.validateCountry}" onchange="onsubmit()" valueChangeListener="#{initapp.getNamesCityByCountry}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Choisir un Pays --" class="bold"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{initapp.allCountry}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.namecountry_fr_fr}" itemValue="#{country.idcountry}"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="countryMessage" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
    <h:message id="countryMessage" for="#{val['inscription.country']}" errorClass="erreur" /><br />
</div>
```

Then in my backing bean, having for scope Application, I do this to be able to execute each time the method in charge to retrieve the list of cities according to the country:

```
public void getNamesCityByCountry(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    String idselect = e.getNewValue().toString();
    Integer value = new Integer(idselect);
    this.msApplication.setListCity(this.msApplication.getIMetierLocal().getAllCity(value));
}
```

And now in the facelet, I do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="#{val['inscription.city']}"><h:outputText value="#{val['inscription.city']}"/> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Choisir une Ville --" class="bold"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="#{val['inscription.city']}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{valinitapp['requiredcity']}" value="#{manageuser.city}" styleClass="form-control" validator="#{manageuser.validateCity}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Choisir une Ville --" class="bold"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{initapp.allCityByNameCountry}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.namecity}" itemValue="#{city.idcity}"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="cityMessage" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
    <h:message id="cityMessage" for="#{val['inscription.city']}" errorClass="erreur" /><br />
</div>
```

In my backing bean:

```
public List<City> getAllCityByNameCountry() {
    return this.msApplication.getListCity();
}
```

I want to run the method (getAllCityByNameCountry ()) above each time to have only the list of cities according to the countries.